# Undelete git repo in Kallithea

Tags: git, rhodecode, undelete, kallithea

I want to undelete a git repo which was deleted in Kallithea.

Kallithea does not delete the git repo, it renames them to this:

```
rm__20140912_181018_206281__myrepo...
```

Just renaming to `myrepo...` did not help.

How can I enable this repo again?

Comment: On creating new tags, see http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/create-tags

Comment: I'm not sure about Kallithea, but in RhodeCode you simply need to change the name to original, and also rename internal .hg dir and remove the rm__ prefix from it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it: You need to rescan the repositories:

Admin / Settings / Remap and Rescan